# Given a function $f$ such that $f' \geq 0$, $f'' \geq 0$ find $\lim_{x \to \infty } f(x)=0$.

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

Let $f :(a, \infty ) \to \mathbb{R} $ nonconstant bounded twice differentiable function such that $f' \geq 0$ and $f'' \geq 0$ on $(a ,\infty )$

Prove $$\lim_{x \to + \infty } f(x) =0$$

I have the solution to this problem, which reads

Since $f' \geq 0$ and $f'' \geq 0$ then $f,f'$ are nondecreasing so the limits at infinity exist.

Set $l := \lim_{x + \to \infty } f(x)$ the by L'Hospital rule it's $$0=\lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{f(x)}{x} =\lim_{x \to + \infty } f'(x)$$

Since $f' \geq 0$ and nondecreasing then $f'=0$ on $(a, \infty )$ so $f$ is constant, contradiction.

I don't understand this proof, first of all I don't understand what is the hypothesis that leads to a contradiction, since we are trying to show that $\lim_{x \to + \infty } f(x) =0$, I suspect that the hypothesis (for contradiction) should have been $\lim_{x \to + \infty } f(x) \neq 0$ but it's not that clear to me what the hypothesis is.

Second, the author uses L'HOSPITAL rule on $\lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{f(x)}{x}$, but to use L'Hospital rule the function under the limit must be either$0/0$ or $\infty / \infty $, here since $x$ tends to $\infty$ then $f(x)$ must tend to infinity as $x$ goes to infinity in order to apply the L'Hospital rule, so I am guessing that the author assumed (for contradiction) that $\lim_{x \to + \infty } f(x)=\infty $ but if that's the cases then contradicting this would mean that $\lim_{x \to + \infty }$ is just finite but not necessarily $0$.

What am I missing, can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

The solution given actually proves that either $f$ is a  constant or $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)_=\infty$. But $f$ is bounded so the latter possibility does not exist. The conclusion is: There is no such function!

L'Hopital's Rule is applicable as long as the denominator tends to $\infty$ so the given solution is correct.

[There is no bounded increasing non-constant convex function on $(a,\infty)$].

Comment: But $f$ is given to be nonconstant, how can $f(x)=1$ be a counterexample?

Comment: @Kthamil I was supposed to delete the first sentence but I forgot.